# Java class FileSystem & FileSystems, what is the difference between them? When to use one over the other?

Tags: java, filesystems

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of IO. I have encountered two Java classes that are very similar, FileSystem and FileSystems. What is the difference between them? When to use one over the other?

Comment: Did you actually look at the javadoc of [`FileSystems`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html) and [`FileSystem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html). All methods in `FileSystems` are static and return an instance of `FileSystem`. `FileSystem` represents a ... (wait for it) ... file system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`FileSystems`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html) is an utility class/factory that is only used to get instances of [`FileSystem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html). Refer to the [class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html) for the methods in the `FileSystems` class.

Basically, you will never use `FileSystems` except when you want to get an instance of `FileSystem`. For all other use cases, yo uwould only want to use `FileSystem`.